# Is this $\mathbb{Z}_2^n$?

Tags: group-theory

What group is formed by binary strings of a fixed length, $n$, and the XOR operation (^)?

For example, we have:

For $n=1$:

```
A^B = B^A = B
A^A = B^B = A
```

For $n=2$:

```
AA ^ AB = AB = AB ^ AA
BB ^ AB = BA = AB ^ BB
```

For $n=3$:

```
ABA ^ BAA = BBA
```

etc

I reckon it is written $\mathbb{Z}_2^n$ but I would like someone to either confirm this or tell me why I am wrong.

Comment: I'm a bit confused by the notation here.  Doesn't $A \star A = B \star B =A$ imply $A =\mathrm{id}$?

Comment: @AWalker, I thought it would be, yes.

Comment: I realize now that $A$ and $B$ refer to your bits, not your group elements (for $n \geq 1$).

Comment: @AWalker, ah, I see, I will add quotes ;)

Comment: @AWalker ... or what you did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering bit strings of length $n$ as $n$-tuples of elements of $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$, the XOR operation is simply the addition in $(\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z)^n$.
So, yes, this "is" just the group  $(\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z)^n$.

Comment: Cool :) That's what I was thinking.